# install g++ 4.8 in ubuntu 13.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, g++4.8

I used:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test    
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install g++-4.8
```

in ubuntu 13.04 to **install g++4.8**. but when I wanted to compile a **c++** program,for example world.cpp and I wrote g++ world.cpp  I received:

```
/usr/local/bin/ld: this linker was not configured to use sysroots
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am new to linux. I can not solve my problem with [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/347466/configure-error-c-compiler-cannot-create-executables)

Comment: Wrong place to ask. I guess your `/usr/local/bin/ld` was not installed thru some Ubuntu package (it would be `/usr/bin/ld`). Did you try running `/usr/bin/g++` instead of just `g++` (you might have some `PATH` related issue)?

Answer (score 2):

Better to install meta-package build-essential that consists of all typically needed soft for compilation.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Comment: Hello. I run your code. But my problem is unsolved yet.

Comment: Hello. I got it. According to the Debian policy packages shouldn't install their bins into /usr/local/bin/*. According to the Debian policy packages shouldn't install their bins into /usr/local/bin/*.
So, your problem is system finds not standars ld in /usr/local/bin rather than system ld. I don't know from where you got it ld, but probubly you don't need it. So, remove your ld from /usr/local/bin OR put /usr/bin rather in PATH. For that add a next line to your ~/.bashrc:
export PATH="/usr/bin:$PATH"

Comment: Hello. Thank you very much. It worked for me.But because I am new to linux, I want to add an explanation for /.bashrc. When I run your line,I found /.bashrc in home folder after I pressed ctrl+h.Thank you again.